# Android Choose Image in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, uri

I'm getting quite confused in this. check my code

```
// Read bitmap
public Bitmap readBitmap(Uri selectedImage) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
    try {
        fileDescriptor = appContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(selectedImage,"r");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);
            fileDescriptor.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return bm;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        bitmap = readBitmap(filePath);
        SuggestImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error here

```
bitmap = readBitmap(filePath);
```

saying incompatible type required int but when i put and int it says cannot be applied. need a help thank you

I think because its in a fragment. i think the problem is i cant get the ContentResolver but i'm not sure

Comment: https://github.com/coomar2841/android-multipicker-library

Comment: what is a `bitmap` variable?

Comment: its Bitmap bitmap;

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a button `editPic` in your fragment on click on which you have to choose image from gallery. Use the following code to implement **Pick from Gallery**

```
editPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    // ******** code for crop image
                    i.putExtra("crop", "true");
                    i.putExtra("aspectX", 100);
                    i.putExtra("aspectY", 100);
                    i.putExtra("outputX", 300);
                    i.putExtra("outputY", 300);
                    try {
                        i.putExtra("return-data", true);
                        startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Picture"), 0);
                    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        });
```

and use the code below for `onActivityResult` in your fragment

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            try {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("data"); // use this bitmap
                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //set image to imageView
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it will work for you.